# Find the order of the pole of $f(z)=\frac{e^{-z}}{z(\cos{z}-1)}$ at $z=0.$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> Let
>
> $$f(z)=\frac{e^{-z}}{z(\cos{z}-1)}$$
>
> a) Determine the order of $f$:s pole at $z=0$.
>
> b) Find the four first terms $\neq 0$ in $f$:s Laurent expansion valid
>   in the region $\{z:0<|z|<2\pi\}.$
>
> c) Evaluate the integral
>
> $$\int_{|z|=1}f(z) \ dz$$

As soon as I've Laurent expanded $f(z)$ around $z=0$, the answers to a), b) and c) are trivial.

I have that

$$e^{-z}=1-z+\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{z^3}{6}+O(z^4),$$

$$z(\cos{z}-1)=-\frac{z^3}{2}+\frac{z^5}{24}+O(z^7).$$

**EDIT:**

$$\frac{1}{z(\cos{z}-1)}=\frac{1}{-\frac{z^3}{2}+\frac{z^5}{24}+O(z^7)}=-\frac{2}{z^3}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z^2}{12}+O(z^4)}=-\frac{2}{z^3}\left(1+\frac{z^2}{12}+O(z^4)\right)=\left(-\frac{2}{z^3}-\frac{1}{6z}+O(z)\right),$$

so

$$\frac{e^{-z}}{z(\cos{z}-1)}=\left(-\frac{2}{z^3}-\frac{1}{6z}+O(z)\right)\left(1-z+\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{z^3}{6}+O(z^4)\right)$$

$$=-\frac{2}{z^3}+\frac{2}{z^2}-\frac{7}{6z}+\frac{1}{2}+O(z).$$

Now all the assignments follow immediately. $\text{Res}_{0}(f)=-7/6$ so the integral is equal to $-7\pi i/3$, by the residual theorem.

Comment: Check again how you inserted the cosine series. After that, what about extracting the common power and then applying power series inversion to get $?=-2z^{-3}(1+\frac{z^2}{12}+O(z^4))$ is the problem?

Comment: What is power series inversion? Edited the cosine series.

Comment: Computing the inverse of a power series. Assuming a non-zero leading coefficient, this is as expensive as computing the product of power series.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've never computed the inverse of a power series. By inverse I assume you mean the inverse function.

Comment: No, sorry, not the inverse function, the inverse fraction. Just the simple operation that is indicated by your expression. Your second power series with the cosine should have all odd powers.

Comment: @LutzL I now realise how your hint was really good. Please see my edit and tell me if that was what you meant?

Comment: There is still a sign error that I also had to correct in my comment The cosine series has alternating signs, that does not change in the extraction of the common factor: $z(\cos z-1)=-\frac12z^3(1-\frac1{12}z^2+O(z^4))$. So the inverse is, by the rules of the geometric series, $-2z^{-3}(1+\frac1{12}z^2+O(z^4))$.

Comment: This is a really nice way to solve it! I didn't know about this kind of approach to Laurent series. It's extremely powerful! Thank you for sharing that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we may write $f$ as
$$
f(z)=-\frac{e^{-z}(\cos(z)+1)}{z\sin^2(z)}.
$$

My hint is to calculate the limits of the form:
$$
\lim_{z\to z_0}\ (z-z_0)^{n}f(z),
$$
for each $n\in\mathbb N$, with $z_0=0$. If the limit does not converge for any $n\in\mathbb N$, then $z_0$ is essential. If the limit converges to $0$ for some $n\in\mathbb N$, then we consider $n_0$ the first $n$ for which this happens. If $n>1$,then $z_0$ is a pole of order $n-1$. If $n=1$,then $z_0$ is a removable singularity of $f$.

Note that, for $n=3$,
$$
\lim_{z\to z_0}\ (z-z_0)^3f(z) =\lim_{z\to0}\ -\frac{e^{-z}(\cos(z)+1)}{\left(\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\right)^2} = -2.
$$
Then, for any $n>3$,
$$
\lim_{z\to z_0}\ (z-z_0)^nf(z) =\left(\lim_{z\to0}\ z^{n-3}\right)\left(\lim_{z\to0}\ \frac{e^{-z}}{\frac{\cos(z)-1}{z^2}}\right) = 0.
$$
That means that $0$ is a pole of $f$ of order $3$.

This means that the Laurent series of $f$ around $0$ is of the form
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=-3}^{+\infty}a_nz^n,
$$
Then, putting $g(z)=z^3f(z)$, we have that
$$
g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_{n-3}z^n, \forall 0<|z|<r,
$$
for some $r>0$. Since the series has only positive exponents, we may also calculate it at the point $0$. Define $g$ at $0$ by $a_{-3}$. Since $g$ is given by an infinite polynomial which converges in any point of $D(0,r)$, it follows that $g$ is holomorphic in $D(0,r)$. Therefore, the derivative $g^{(j)}$ is continuous for every integer $j\geq0$ and the $k$-th coefficient of the expansion of $g$ equals to $\frac{1}{k!}g^{(j)}(0)$. Using these facts we get:
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
a_{-3} &  =g(0)=\lim_{z\to0} g(z) = \lim_{z\to0}\ -\frac{e^{-z}(\cos(z)+1)}{\left(\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\right)^2} = -2; \\
a_{-2} &  =g'(0)= \displaystyle\lim_{z\to0} g'(z) = \lim_{z\to0}\ \left(-\frac{e^{-z}(\cos(z)+1)}{\left(\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\right)^2}\right)' \\
& = \displaystyle\lim_{z\to0}\ -\frac{\left[-e^{-z}(\cos(z)+1)+e^{-z}(-\sin(z))\right]\left(\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\right)^2 - 2\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\left(\frac{z\cos(z)-\sin(z)}{z^2}\right)}{\left(\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\right)^4},
\end{array}
$$
and using L'Hopital we see that $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to0}\frac{z\cos(z)-\sin(z)}{z^2}=0$, and consequently,
$$
a_{-2} = e^{-0}(\cos(0)+1)+e^{-0}\sin(0) = 2;
$$
To continue, we must evaluate:
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
a_{-1} &  =g''(0)=\lim_{z\to0} g''(z) = \lim_{z\to0}\ \left(\frac{e^{-z}(\cos(z)+1)}{\left(\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\right)^2}\right)''; \\
a_{0} &  =g^{(3)}(0)=\lim_{z\to0} g^{(3)}(z) = \lim_{z\to0}\ \left(\frac{e^{-z}(\cos(z)+1)}{\left(\frac{\sin(z)}{z}\right)^2}\right)^{(3)}.
\end{array}
$$

This is a way to solve this exercise. The calculations of the two last limits are very extense, I only calculated until the second one. I'm also very curious about a way to expand the Laurent series of this function directly. I hope it was helpful.

Comment: This seems to be quite tedious just to find the order of the pole. Also, the answer is that the pole is of order 3, not 2. If we just expand it in Laurent series, a), b) and c) can be done easily.

Comment: Hey, man! Chill a little bit. See, the properties I used and my calculations are correct. I just mistated the conclusion. I got that the first $n$for which the limit is $0$ is$n=4$, so the pole must be of order $3$. I just wrote the number $2$ instead of $3$ by mistake. Still the calculations fine.

Comment: Also, I guess it si very difficult to find the Laurent expansion so easily. There is a reason for the exercise doesn't ask you to calculate the entire series. Anyway, I shall complete my answer. Once we know that $0$ is a pole of order $3$ we know that the function $z^3f(z)$ can be expressed a infinite polynomial with no negative exponents...

Comment: I managed to Laurent expand it. Please see my edit. It seems a bit easier to do that, although your calculations seem to be correct. But on a test, I'll be very time restricted.

Answer (score 0):

For determining the order of the pole at $z=0$, we recall that

> $z_0$ is a zero of order $k$ for $f(z)$ if and only if $f(z_0)=f'(z_0)=...=f^{k-1}(z_0)=0$ and $f^k(z_0)\neq 0$.

We consider $g(z)=z\cos(z)-z$. Now,
\begin{align}
g(z)&=z\cos(z)-z\implies g(0)=0 \\
g'(z)&=-z\sin(z)+\cos(z)-1\implies g'(0)=0 \\
g''(z)&=-z\cos(z)-2\sin(z)\implies g''(0)=0 \\
g'''(z)&=z\sin(z)-3\cos(z)\implies g'''(0)=-3\neq 0.
\end{align}
Hence, we conclude that $g(z)$ is a zero of order $3$, which implies that $\frac{1}{g(z)}$ is a pole of order $3$.

We also note the numerator $e^{-z}$ does not differ this result, as for $z=0$ this is a zero of order $0$, meaning $3-0$ is still a pole of order $3$.

Comment: This was neat, thanks!

Comment: I am glad you found it helpful :) If you are looking for more practice, I have posted a similar question that is yet to be answered https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2976785/laurent-series-for-fz-frac2z12-frac5z-5

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go at this.